# How to stop current NSOperation?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm using `NSOperationQueue`, and `NSOperation` for running some function on background click.
But I want to be able, when user clicks some button, stop that Operation.

How can I do it?

Something like, `[currentoperation stop];`
`Cancel` - won't work me. I want to stop immediately.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be calling the `-cancel` method, and the operation itself has to support being cancelled by monitoring the `isCancelled` property/keypath and safely stopping when its value becomes `YES`. If the NSOperation is your own, you will probably have to create a custom subclass to implement this functionality. You cannot (safely) force an arbitrary operation to immediately stop. It has to support being cancelled.

Answer (score 8):

You can't stop immediately by using anything Apple provides with `NSOperation`. You can use `-[cancel]` as other people have suggested here, but the current operation will still run until completion. One way of getting close to use `-[isCancelled]` inside of your operation and sprinkle that throughout the code (especially in long running loops). Something like:

```
- (void)main {
    // do a little work
    if ([self isCancelled]) { return; }

    // do a little more work
    if ([self isCancelled]) { return; }
}
```

This way you'll get things stopped relatively soon.

If you're looking to really force the thread to stop, you may need to look into signal handling. There's a [threaded example here](http://www.apuebook.com/threadsig.html). Sending a custom signal to a specific thread, you may be able to then terminate that thread in some way. This will be a lot more work, though, and is probably much more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

you use `cancel`, and test whether `self` (the `NSOperation`) has been cancelled during execution.